# ¿Cómo puedo pasar este código a método en Java?

Tags: java

Estoy desarrollando un sistema de información dedicado a la asistencia de empleados de una empresa, el cual, permita calcular sueldos en base a las horas trabajadas (es para un proyecto escolar). Tengo este código que me permite determinar cuantos segundos existen entre un instante y otro (es decir, hora de entrada y hora de salida) para luego convertir dichos segundos a horas y poder generar las horas trabajadas y horas extra.

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Duracion {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        
        long segundosTrabajados;
        double totalHoras, horasExtra = 0, horasTrabajadas;
        
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a");
        
        Instant horaEntrada = Instant.now();
        
        OffsetDateTime enter = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        String entrada = dtf.format(enter);
        System.out.println("Hora de entrada: " + entrada);
        /* … El código que se está midiendo comienza … */
 
        // dormir por X segundos, simulando los segundos trabajados del empleado 
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(32400);
 
        /*… El código que se está midiendo termina… */
        Instant horaSalida = Instant.now();
        
        OffsetDateTime out = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        String salida = dtf.format(out);
        System.out.println("Hora de salida: " + salida);
 
        Duration duracion = Duration.between(horaEntrada, horaSalida);
 
        segundosTrabajados = duracion.getSeconds();
        
        totalHoras = segundosTrabajados / 3600;
        
        if(totalHoras > 8) {
            horasExtra = totalHoras - 8;
            horasTrabajadas = totalHoras - horasExtra;
            System.out.println("Horas trabajadas: " + horasTrabajadas + " horas.");
            System.out.println("Horas extra: " + horasExtra + " horas.");
        } else {
            horasTrabajadas = totalHoras;
            System.out.println("Horas trabajadas: " + horasTrabajadas + " horas.");
            System.out.println("Horas extra: " + horasExtra + " horas.");
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Mi consulta es: ¿cómo puedo transformar dicho código a un método para utilizarlo rápidamente cuando un empleado X ingrese a trabajar y viceversa? Teniendo en cuenta que posteriormente trabajaré con base de datos MySQL. Soy nuevo en POO y quisiera saber la forma correcta y optimizada de realizarlo, y a su vez, aprender en el proceso. Gracias de antemano por sus respuestas, estoy atento y cualquier ayuda o recomendación será bien recibida.

Comment: *¿cómo puedo transformar dicho código a un método para utilizarlo rápidamente cuando un empleado X ingrese a trabajar y viceversa?* Ya tienes ese código en un método que se llama `main`, que como ya sabrás es el punto de entrada de los programas en Java. Si quieres ejecutar ese código en otro método simplemente crea ese método y pon dentro el código, retornando el valor de `totalHoras`. ¿Tienes alguna dificultad para hacer eso? ¿Cuál es? Si en ese proceso tienes algún problema te ayudaremos y aprenderás mucho más que si te damos el trabajo ya hecho.

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias por comentar amigo. Principalmente se me dificulta estructurar el código en forma de métodos para requerirlos cuando X empleado entre y salga de trabajar, estoy realizando varias pruebas pero lo que quiero es una forma de que cuando un empleado entre a trabajar llamar al método `entrada();` y al salir `salida();` por ejemplo, y que le envíe a la base de datos el total de horas y horas extra (si aplica). En ese aspecto tengo dificultades, solo requiero de un punto de partida para realizarlo, pero por el momento; estoy en blanco.

Comment: Debes pensar las clases como entidades que sirven para encapsular / resolver un problema y el orden que des al código es muy importante. La POO funciona como en la vida real. ¿Quieres expresar un empleado?, pues crea una clase `Empleado`, ¿quieres manejar duración de un empleado en el trabajo?, pues crea una clase `Duracion` (eso ya lo tienes). Luego, ensambla toda tu lógica en una clase principal, en la cual puedes poner el método `main` y allí crear las instancias de `Empleado`, de `Duracion`, etc. Luego, habrá que reflejar cómo se determina la entrada y la salida de un empleado ...

Comment: ... cómo guardar esos datos en la BD, etc, etc, todo eso mediante clases que manejen esa lógica. Es algo un poco amplio para resolverlo en una sola pregunta, por eso te he sugerido que empieces a estructurar tu código de una forma lógica y una vez hecho eso nos digas el problema concreto que tienes. Puede que te encuentres con varios problemas, no importa, te ayudaremos a resolverlos todos (por cada problema nuevo debes plantear una nueva pregunta), pero no podemos hacer el programa por ti, ni organizarte el código.

Comment: @A.Cedano Entiendo amigo, muchas gracias por sus recomendaciones y consejos. Su respuesta me ha dado un punto de partida para empezar a trabajar, justo lo que necesitaba! En caso de encontrarme con un obstáculo o con un problema; ¿cómo podría volverme a comunicar con usted? ¿respondo de nuevo por este medio? No sé cómo funciona :/.

Comment: Para este caso, puedes editar esta misma pregunta, añadiendo el código que tienes, y los problemas o errores que tienes, o lo que no entiendes. Y, para problemas posteriores, puedes abrir una nueva pregunta. Esto no funciona a modo de SAT, sino que es una comunidad de usuarios, en las que miembros con más conocimiento y experiencia pueden ayudarte a resolver problemas, sea respondiendo a tu pregunta, sea pidiéndote aclaraciones y sugiriéndote cosas en comentarios. Lo bueno es que a veces puedes tener varios puntos de vista y quedarte con el que mejor te convenga.

Comment: @A.Cedano Un millón de gracias, hermano. Gracias por aclararme las dudas que tenía sobre cómo estructurar mis clases para empezar a trabajar. Saludos!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public class Principal { 

    public static void main( String args[] ) {
       Control con = new Control();
       Liquidacion liq = new Liquidacion();
       Empleado pepe = new Empleado( "Pepe" );
       con.entro( pepe );
       con.salio( pepe );
       liq.liquidacion( pepe );
    }
}
```

La clase **Control**.

```
public class Control { 

   public void entro( Empleado empleado ) {
      empleado.setHoraEntrada( Instant.now() );
      horaActual();
   }
    
   public void salio( Empleado empleado ) {
      empleado.setHoraSalida( Instant.now() );
      horaActual();
   }
    
   private String horaEnCadena( OffsetDateTime hora) {
      return dtf.format( hora );
   }
    
   private void horaActual() {
      OffsetDateTime ahora = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneId.systemDefault() );
      return dtf.format( ahora );
   }
}
```

La clase **Liquidacion**.

```
public class Liquidacion {

   public void liquidacion( Empleado empleado ) {
      double totalHoras = empleado.getHorasTrabajadas();
      double tiposHoras[] = horasTrabajadas( totalHoras );
      int precioHoraNormal = 10;
      int precioHoraExtra = 15;
      double valorHorasNormales = precioHoraNormal * tiposHoras[ 0 ];
      double valorHorasExtras = precioHoraExtra * tiposHoras[ 1 ];
      double totalParaAbonar = valorHorasNormales + valorHorasExtras;
      System.out.println( "Abonar a " + empleado.getNombre() + " $" + totalParaAbonar );
   }

   private double[] horasTrabajadas( double totalHoras ) {
      double horasExtra = 0, horasTrabajadas;
      if( totalHoras > 8 ) {
         horasExtra = totalHoras - 8;
         horasTrabajadas = totalHoras - horasExtra;
      }
      else {
         horasTrabajadas = totalHoras;
      }
      double salida[] = { horasTrabajadas, horasExtra };
      return salida;
   }
}
```

La clase **Empleado**:

```
public class Empleado {
   Instant horaEntrada;
   Instant horaSalida;
   private String nombre;

   public Empleado( String nomb ) {
      nombre = nomb;
   }

   public String getNombre() {
      return nombre;
   }
   public void setHoraEntrada( Instant hora ) {
      horaEntrada = hora;
   }

   public void setHoraSalida( Instant hora ) {
      horaSalida = hora;
   } 

   public double getHorasTrabajadas() {
      Duration duracion = Duration.between( horaEntrada, horaSalida );
      long segundosTrabajados = duracion.getSeconds();        
      return segundosTrabajados / 3600;
   }
}
```

Bueno, acá te dejo un ejemplo desarrollado a partir de tu código, pero usando la POO.
El secreto: clases y métodos pequeños y reutilizables.
Me tomé el atrevimiento de extender un poco la funcionalidad de **Liquidacion**, para que se vea una posible utilización.

La clase **Empleado**, guarda los datos del mismo, tiene getters que devuelven esos datos, y un método que devuelve las horas trabajadas (también se puede implementar en **Liquidacion**).

Liquidacion tiene dos métodos, uno privado (el que tenías implementado) y uno publico, que se encarga de calcular lo que corresponde pagar y mostrarlo.

Control solo se encarga de "fichar", y mostrar la hora.

Con Principal manejamos todo, creamos el empleado, instanciamos las clases auxiliares, hacemos que el empleado "fiche", y luego llamamos a liquidacion para que haga lo suyo.

PD's:
Esto es solo un modelo, que adolece de algunas inconsistencias.
Si quieres probarlo tienes que modificar lo que devuelve el "empleado" para "horasTrabajadas", ya que dado que la entrada y la salida se hacen en el mismo momento, siempre imprimirá monto a pagar "0.0".

Comment: Saludos amigo! Agradecido por tu colaboración y por tomarte el tiempo de ayudarme. El código junto con la información que me suministras sin duda alguna serán de gran ayuda en el proyecto que estoy realizando, no lo copiaré igual sino que tomaré tu respuesta como un punto inicial para hacer mi propio código y poder aprender un poco más sobre POO en Java. Gracias una vez más por tu tiempo, lo valoro, amigo. Saludos!

Comment: @L.DaCosta, Un placer ayudarte!!.